# libgdx custom ViewPort

Tags: android, libgdx, screen, viewport

I need a `ViewPort` with following the properties :

- maintain aspect ratio
- fill `x` axis
- always align the `top` of the screen
- cut the bottom if `screenHeight < viewPortHeight`

Do I need to extend `ViewPort` or use existing implementations with some configurations, to achieve such behavior ?

[image]

Comment: do you have a visual of what you want as a result? Or an example ?

Comment: [This](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-17-Viewports.aspx) may be able to help you. If you still can't achieve what you want to, try [custom View Ports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#customviewport)